# Composer: virtual packages in provide section

Tags: package, composer-php, virtual

Given that Composer can work with [**virtual** packages in `provide`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#provide) section of `composer.json` file, how are the versions managed of those virtual packages if no one holds the responsibility?

I mean if anyone can create *"evil"* package stating it `provide`-s specific virtual package (for which there is no repo anywhere), than they can specify whatever version they like. This could perhaps collide with other *"good"* packages, right?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, this "virtual package" feature hasn't been widely used, and it definitely has its drawbacks due to the way it is currently implemented.

If you take a look at [this search result](https://packagist.org/search/?q=psr%2Flog-im) on Packagist, you'll see the three top packages being `psr/log` (the real interface package), `psr/log` (a virtual package used by two other real packages, but in the wrong way) and `psr/log-implementation` (used by plenty of packages, including `monolog/monolog`).

This example illustrates that people will misunderstand this feature and do the wrong thing. You cannot *provide* `psr/log` because that is a real package that has a real interface definition. It makes even less sense to *require* `psr/log` and at the same time also *provide* it.

You also correctly spotted that there is no central entity that decides which versions of a virtual package should exist, let alone which virtual package names should exist. Which isn't that much of a problem because deciding on the names of *real* packages is done the same way: One developer thinks of a name, and that's all. It's unlikely that this procedure creates involuntary conflicts because usually the Github account name is used as the vendor name, and Github has already made them unique. Malicious conflicts don't really exist in the real world, as [Jordi has pointed out in his blog](https://seld.be/notes/typo-squatting-and-packagist), due to the general structure Composer uses to name packages.

Back to the virtual package feature: There are two blog postings discussing it.

The first [explains using this feature](https://devedge.wordpress.com/2014/09/27/composer-and-virtual-packages/) with the example of the virtual `psr/log-implementation` package mentioned above. I won't replicate that tutorial-like text here.

The [second (linked and replied to at the end of the first) discusses what's bad](https://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/10/composer-provide-and-dependency-inversion/) about the whole approach of virtual packages.

Some of the points:

> 1) Strictly speaking (as in, would the code compile), the code from the library itself doesn't need a package that provides `psr/log-implementation`. It just needs the `LoggerInterface` (which happens to be in the `psr/log` package).
>
> 4) `psr/log-implementation`, or any virtual package for that matter, is very problematic as a package. There is no definition of this virtual package. [...]
>
> 5) Some day, someone may decide to introduce another virtual package, called `the-real-psr/log-implementation` (they can easily do that, right?). Such packages may be completely exchangeable with existing `psr/log-implementation` packages, but in order to be useful, every existing PSR-3 compliant logger package needs to mention that virtual package too in their provide section. [...]

With all these problems and uncertainties existing for good packages, it is no surprise that they do not really use this feature very much.

However, you cannot abuse it for bad things in the way you outline it in your question. Yes, any package can declare that it *provides* any other package. But just like it happened with `psr/log`, having a package declaring that it provides another package will not magically make everyone download that package. The way it works is a package declares that it provides another package, and by *requiring* this package, the virtual package also gets included and will fulfill any dependencies of *other* packages onto the virtual package.

But not requiring the package *providing* stuff will leave everything in it out of the equation.

In order to include bad software someone has to `require` it. This is best done as an indirect dependency of an innocent looking library, and requires the help of an unsuspecting developer that actively pulls this code without properly reviewing it.

Which probably is my central point for everything: If you pull in someones code into your own project, make sure you understand what that code does by reviewing it (which isn't only about malicious things, but also basic code quality, because some day you may be forced to debug a problem), or make sure you can trust that source enough to not do bad things to you. However, your own code base is not affected by packages you do not require (the last bug with such an effect was handling `replace` information, but I don't find that issue right now).

Comment: (part 1/2) Thank you @Sven for taking the time to explain the problematic to me to such extent. However it still does not provide reasonable answer to my "version" question. You mentioned package names, but I don't think those are comparable to versions of virtual packages. 
Simply because for a package there is a single repository - single responsible person, if you will.

Comment: (part 2/2) On the other hand, anyone can just provide any virtual package (in any version) they can think of. There is no one explicitly managing the life cycle of said virtual package. And so even if one person was first to `provide` the package and could be considered a _maintainer_, anyone can provide it too in another version, thusly spoiling any _maintainers'_ plans of future packages' development.

Comment: You are right, I ignored the "version" part. But as you said yourself, versions are as problematic as names. A version is created by any package that `provides` a virtual package in a version. However, the way the packages work is that an application will require a lib which `requires` a virtual package (like `psr/log-implementation) in a version range, and another lib that provides this version. No other package can force to be considered as a better alternative by providing a higher compatible version for the virtual package.