# Silvestripe 4.4 can't instal omnipay/paypal

Tags: paypal, composer-php, silverstripe, omnipay

With silverstripe 4.4 and silvershop, I have tried a hundred variations to get `omnipay/paypal` installed with composer.

No matter what I try it doesn't install.

Has anybody got it working with ss4.4 ?

Whats wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your error message, you are missing the package `php-http/client-implementation`.

If you get a quick look at this from the [Packagist](https://packagist.org/providers/php-http/client-implementation?query=php-http%2Fclient-implementation), you'll see that this package is actually a virtual package, so you need one of the packages that define themselves as `php-http/client-implementation`, since it is not a real package, you have to choose one.

If you don't know which to choose, maybe choose the first one from the [Packagist](https://packagist.org/providers/php-http/client-implementation).
*For what it worth, I actually had pretty good impression of guzzle packages in the past, so I would say it is a safe bet.*

So you can fix your issue by doing

```
composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter
```

Then running

```
composer require omnipay/paypal
```

Or you can even do it in one go:

```
$ composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter omnipay/paypal
composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter omnipay/paypal
Using version ^2.0 for php-http/guzzle6-adapter
Using version ^3.0 for omnipay/paypal
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 21 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing php-http/promise (v1.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/http-client (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/httplug (v2.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing moneyphp/money (v3.2.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.12.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.12.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.12.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/mime (v4.3.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.3.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/discovery (1.7.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing clue/stream-filter (v1.4.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/message-factory (v1.0.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/message (1.8.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.6.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/guzzle6-adapter (v2.0.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing omnipay/common (v3.0.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing omnipay/paypal (v3.0.2): Downloading (100%)         
moneyphp/money suggests installing ext-bcmath (Calculate without integer limits)
moneyphp/money suggests installing ext-gmp (Calculate without integer limits)
moneyphp/money suggests installing ext-intl (Format Money objects with intl)
moneyphp/money suggests installing florianv/swap (Exchange rates library for PHP)
moneyphp/money suggests installing florianv/exchanger (Exchange rates library for PHP)
moneyphp/money suggests installing psr/cache-implementation (Used for Currency caching)
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn suggests installing ext-intl (For best performance)
php-http/discovery suggests installing puli/composer-plugin (Sets up Puli which is recommended for Discovery to work. Check http://docs.php-http.org/en/latest/discovery.html for more details.)
php-http/message suggests installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (Used with Diactoros Factories)
php-http/message suggests installing slim/slim (Used with Slim Framework PSR-7 implementation)
guzzlehttp/psr7 suggests installing zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner (Emit PSR-7 responses)
guzzlehttp/guzzle suggests installing psr/log (Required for using the Log middleware)
omnipay/common suggests installing league/omnipay (The default Omnipay package provides a default HTTP Adapter.)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

*More on virtual packages:*

- https://github.com/php-http/guzzle6-adapter/blob/4b491b78e1b24ca941e6ca925f48a63e6a2d9a45/composer.json#L29
- https://github.com/php-http/guzzle6-adapter/blob/4b491b78e1b24ca941e6ca925f48a63e6a2d9a45/composer.json#L29
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489529/2123530

Comment: thanks a lot! this is very helpful! with another lots of tries and errors i made my first sandbox paypal transaction. (only worked with ss4.2, php7.2 !important ?) AND: SYMLINKS in public/resources/vendor/.... REALLY??? still many questions .... have a nice day. sepp.